# Why is $f = f_{0} + \sum_{i}\alpha_{i}X_{i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}^{n} \sum_{j}^{n}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$ the standard quadratic form in n dimensions?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, numerical-methods

The claim that $$f = f_{0} + \sum_{i}\alpha_{i}X_{i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}^{n}  \sum_{j}^{n}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$$

is the standard quadratic form for $n$ dimensions, where $\alpha$ is some $ 1 \times n$ matrix and X some $n \times n$ matrix,

appears in the first page of the following paper:
http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Fletcher-Powell.pdf

I want to understand why this equation holds.

---

It makes sense that, when the input matrix, $X$, is in one dimension ($n = 1$), the above equation would give the equation of a quadratic in algebra: $f(x) = c + bx + ax^2$.

If we take the quadratic given by ($n = 2$) to be a parabaloid, then the above equation also makes sense.

I do not understand why, for higher dimensions ($n > 2$), the quadratic equation is what the above formula gives.

---

As an aside, could someone show why the gradient of the equation above is just $AX + \alpha$

For example, when $(n = 2)$, the expansion above is:

$ f_{0} + \alpha_{1}X_{1} + \alpha_{2}X_{2} + \frac{1}{2}(A_{11}X_{1}X_{1} + A_{12}X_{1}X_{2} + A_{21}X_{2}X_{1} + A_{22}X_{2}X_{2})$

What differentiation of this expansion leads to the result for the gradient?

Comment: The gradient given as $\sum_{i}A_{i}X_{i} + A$ does not look correct. The gradient should be a vector. As for the main question, given that $A_{ij}=A_{ji}$ there is not much of a choice except for the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my post, so that the gradient and expansion now shown are correct. Why is $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$? That can only be true if A is symmetric, which is not a precondition for the method the linked paper shows.

Comment: that was a little lie, but only half one. If you have some matrix $A'$ you can choose a new one by defining $A=\frac12 (A'+A'^{T})$ that has $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$ without changing the result.

Comment: If, into $\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n}A_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$, I substituted $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{T})$, I would have the following for the last term: $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}^{n}\sum_{j}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(A + A^{T})X_{i}X_{j}$$ Distributing would give the original term plus a sum of terms like $A'_{ij}X_{i}X_{j}$ Am i right that this term must = 0?

Comment: Now that I've correctly expanded the $n = 2$ sequence, can you show what differentiation produces the formula for the gradient? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just very short: $\frac{\partial}{\partial X_k}X_iX_j = (\frac{\partial}{\partial X_k}X_i)X_j + X_i\frac{\partial}{\partial X_k}X_j=\delta_{ik}X_j+X_i\delta_{kj}$

$\sum_i\sum_jA_{ij}\delta_{ik}X_j + \sum_i\sum_jA_{ij}\delta_{jk}X_i=\sum_jA_{kj}X_j+\sum_iA_{ki}X_i=2\sum_jA_{kj}X_j$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34247/discussion-between-muno-and-gyro-gearloose).